# Close Bootstrap modal with jQuery or Javascript on windows resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

How can i close a Bootstrap modal if the browser windows is width is less than 700px? I have tried with jQuery like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 700) {

    $("#modal").hide( 0, function() {});
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
    $(".modal-backdrop").hide( 0, function() {});
 }
});
```

I have the content of the modal in 50% of the page and when the window is less than 700px the content moves into the modal. Is working great but if i resize the windows with the method above i will have some problems and i will have to press the button to open the modal twice. If i dont resize the windows and i close the modal with the X than it works great so i have to find a way to close the modal when the windows is resized.

Comment: Would adding media screen CSS work? Like the modal is just hidden when its small then would reappear when its resized or do you want it to actually close?

Comment: Also in your function you could probably do $(close button).click()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you should try

```
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```

instead of

```
$('#modal').hide();
```